# Подтянуть несколько таблиц на страницу

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте.
Есть страница заказа, и на неё должны подтягиваться данные с нескольких таблиц БД. Но дело в том, что при использовании mysql_fetch_assoc получается преобразовать только данные в ассоциативный массив из первой таблицы. При повторной попытке использовать функцию получаю в ответ false.

Пробовал запихнуть эту функцию ещё в одну функцию - результат такой же.
Пробовал с двух таблиц тащить данные запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM `modificators` , `pricing`
```

В SQL данные нормально подтягиваются, но вот в PHP только данные первой таблицы.

В общем, не знаю даже что делать.

Код(в комментариях показал, где используется mysql_fetch_assoc):

```
<?php 

function priceCalc($quantity_item, $modificator_sum, $item_price){
    $total_amout = $quantity_item * ($item_price + $modificator_sum);   
    return $total_amout;
}

function sqlDataQuery($sql_connection, $table, $other_request){
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `".$table."` ".$other_request;
    $sql_response = mysql_query($sql_query) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

    return $sql_response;
}


    require_once('db.php');
    $sql_connection = dbConnect();


    $sql_response = sqlDataQuery($sql_connection, 'modificators', '');

    $input = [];
    $i = 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_response)){ // ПЕРВОЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕ
        $input[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }


    $data = [];

    foreach($input as $d){
        $gId = $d['id_group'];


        if(!isset($data[$gId])){
            $data[$gId] = [
                    'pricing' => [],
                    'names'   => []
                 ];
        }

        $data[$gId]['pricing'][] = $d['price'];
        $data[$gId]['names'][] = sprintf("%s %+.2f", $d['name'], $d['price']);
    }



    for($b = 0; $b < count($data); $b++){
        $selected_rate = $_POST['mod'.$b];
        $sum_modificators = $sum_modificators + $data[$b]['pricing'][$selected_rate]; 
    }

    $get_price = mysql_fetch_assoc(sqlDataQuery($sql_connection, 'pricing', 'WHERE `id` = 1')); // ВТОРОЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕ

    echo priceCalc($_POST['items'], $sum_modificators, $get_price['price']);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего нужно передавать соединение по ссылке:

```
function sqlDataQuery(&$sql_connection, $table, $other_request)
```

И хорошо бы очищать память с помощью(но это чисто для экономии):

```
mysql_free_result($sql_response);
```

Comment: Вернуло ошибку: Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed; If you would like to pass argument by reference, modify the declaration of sqlDataQuery(). К тому же, первый mysql_fetch_assoc работает, а вот второй - нет. В этом и проблема.